# How to apply a function with multiple arguments to every element of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, array-map, array-walk

I have a method `MyClass#foo(array $array, $argX, $argY, $argZ)` and want to apply it to every element of `$myArray`.

I've tried this with [`array_map(...)`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`array_walk(...)`](http://php.net/array_walk), but they are not flexible enough for a function with a custom signature.

How to apply a method with multiple arguments to every element of an array in PHP (without for iterate with a loop)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php) (maybe in combination with the `use` keyword to have access to the $arg* variables):

```
array_map(function($item) use ($argX, $argY, $argZ) {
    return MyClass::foo($item, $argX, $argY, $argZ);
}, $your_array_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP 5.3+, then you can pass an anonymous function (or closure) as the callback parameter to `array_map`.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($val){
    // Whatever code you want using `$val`.
    // Make sure to `return` a value, though.
}, $myArray);
```

If you want to use *other* variables inside the anonymous function, then you can use the `use` keyword to capture them.

```
$newArray = array_map(function($val) use($argX, $argY, $argZ){
    // Whatever code you want using `$val`,
    // and also `$argX`, `$argY`, `$argZ`.
    // Make sure to `return` a value, though.
}, $myArray);
```

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php